# Write an excel formula in a cell by VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to write an excel formula into a cell by a VBA code. I have a table in "sheets1" named "Table1". In "sheets2", cell "A2" I want to add a formula to subtract first row and final row of column B of "Table1" from "sheets1" so that the user can see the formula in the cell. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Probably.  But, what do you mean by "intractable" - a formula can't exactly be stubborn or argumentative...  Any what do you mean by "so that the user can see the formula in the cell?  You either see the VBA function name, or a non-VBA function placed with `Range.Formula = `...

Comment: By "intractable", are you trying to say "able to be interacted with"? In other words, the user can see the formula in the formula bar and edit it if required

Comment: I have debugged many spreadsheets with stubborn formulae over the years!  And many do insist on arguments! ;-)

Comment: @barrowc revised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be something like this

```
Public Function Substract()
    dim firstRow as Integer
    dim endrow as Integer

    firstrow = IIf(IsEmpty(Sheets("Table1").Range("B1")), Sheets("Table1").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row, 1)
    endrow =  Sheets("Table1").Cells(Sheets("Table1").Rows.count,"B").End(xlUp).Row

    Substract = firstrow  - endrow
End Function
```

Note: You have to Create a Module an put the Code in there

In excel you can call this as a Formular with =Substract()

Comment: but this way there would not be an intractable excel formula

Comment: Than something like
"
=ROW(INDEX(Table1!B:B,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((Table1!B:B<>0),0),0))) -ROW(INDEX(Table1!B:B,MAX((B:B<>"")*(ROW(Table1!B:B)))))
"

have to enter it with Shift+Control+Enter